# Not able to filter Null values before calling a UDF in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame and want to call a sample pyspark udf which would subtract integer 1 from each row (this is just to demonstrate the issue which I am facing).

```
+------+
|number|
+------+
|     1|
|     2|
|     3|
|     4|
|  null|
+------+
```

I have created below udf :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

def test1(x):
  return x-1

test1 = f.udf(test1, IntegerType())
```

I am trying to cal this udf as below :

```
df1 = df.withColumn('test', f.when(f.col('number').isNotNull(),test1(f.col('number'))))
```

I was expecting that my udf would only be called when the value is not null, however, I am getting below error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3906152203954731> in <module>()
----> 1 df1.show()

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    377         """
    378         if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 379             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    380         else:
    381             print(self._jdf.showString(n, int(truncate), vertical))

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o4509.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 123.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.0 in stage 123.0 (TID 353, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 480, in main
    process()
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 472, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(out_iter, outfile)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 456, in dump_stream
    self.serializer.dump_stream(self._batched(iterator), stream)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 149, in dump_stream
    for obj in iterator:
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 445, in _batched
    for item in iterator:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 87, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: f(*a)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/util.py", line 99, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<command-3906152203954725>", line 7, in test1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Can somebody please explain this behavior of Pyspark?

Thanks

I have tried rewriting the udf as below and this works

```
def test(x):
  if x is None:
    return None
  else: return x -1
```

Comment: Please see the answer on the linked duplicate for more details, but the summary is that you must make your `udf`s robust to bad inputs. Since `udf`s can be applied in batch mode, the condition inside the `when` is sometimes ignored.

Comment: Yes, it's the same issue which I faced. Thanks for directing me to it :)

Comment: Also found a databricks document which also states the same thing about UDF evaluation and order. Might be helpful https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python.html